# Powershell DSC - Download MSI file to VM

Tags: powershell, azure

I've tried the following example to download from Azure blob or Azure file share but never got it to work. Is there a way to download files to VM passing credentials or keys?

```
        Import-DSCResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration, xPSDesiredStateConfiguration        

Node webServer  
{           xRemoteFile Installs
                 {
                 DestinationPath = "C:\Scripts"
                 Credential = $StorageCredential
                 Ensure = "Present"
                 SourcePath = "https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/installs"
                 Type = "Directory"
                 Recurse = $true
                 }  
    }
```

I also tried the using File module.

```
    Import-DSCResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration, xPSDesiredStateConfiguration

                Node webServer
                {
                                File Installs
                                {
                                DestinationPath = "C:\Scripts"
                                Credential = $StorageCredential
                                Ensure = "Present"
                                SourcePath = "\\storagename.file.core.windows.net\installs"
                                Type = "Directory"
                                Recurse = $true
                                }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download file from Azure File Share, you could refer to this [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_farnhill/2015/03/15/using-dsc-to-download-from-azure-file-storage-to-an-azure-vm/). Add following script to your script.

```
Configuration SimpleExampleWithCredentials {

  param(

      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]

      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]

      [PSCredential]$Credentials

  )
```

If you use classic VM, you could use the following cmdlets.

```
Set-AzureVMDscExtension -VM $vm -ConfigurationArchive MyConfiguration.ps1.zip -ConfigurationName MyConfiguration -ConfigurationArgument @{ storageCredential= (Get-Credential) }
```

If you use ARM VM, you should use cmdlet [Set-​Azure​Rm​VM​Dsc​Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmdscextension?view=azurermps-4.0.0).

Comment: I am using ARM VM, can you provide an example using Set-​Azure​Rm​VM​Dsc​Extension?

Comment: Hi, do you try this  `Set-AzureRmVMDscExtension -Version 2.21 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMName $vmName  -ArchiveBlobName "Sample.ps1.zip" -ArchiveStorageAccountName "Stg" -ConfigurationName MyConfiguration -ConfigurationArgument @{ storageCredential= (Get-Credential) }`?

Comment: Also, I suggest you could download file to your VM with Custom Script Extension, then use DSC to install them.